# how to find value in (txt) python string

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

i'm new to python world and i'm trying to extract value from text. I try to find the keyword by **re.search('keyword')** , but I want to get the value after keyword

```
text = word1:1434, word2:4446, word3:7171
```

i just want to get the value of word1

i try

```
keyword = 'word1'
before_keyword, keyword, after_keyword = text.partition(keyword)
print(after_keyword)
```

output

```
:1434, word2:4446, word3:7171
```

i just want to get the value of word1 **(1434)**

Comment: try `text.partition('word1:')[2].partition(',')[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can search the text using regular expressions:

```
import re

keyword_regex = r'word1:(\d+)'
text = "word1:1434, word2:4446, word3:7171"
keyword_value = re.search(keyword_regex, text)
print(keyword_value.group(1))
```

The RegEx `word1:(\d+)` searches for the string `word1:` followed by one or more digits. It stops matching when the next character is not a digit. The parentheses around `(\d+)` make this part a *capturing group* which is what enables you to access it later using `keyword_value.group(1)`.

More about regular expressions [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) and Python's `re` module [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Comment: hi its a use full and easy . good

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Text input is a string not dict; then

```
text = "word1:1434, word2:4446, word3:7171"
keyword = 'word1'
print(text.split(keyword+":")[1].split(",")[0])
```

Hope this helps...